# Updating a pom.xml version during the buildr release process

Tags: ruby, jruby, buildr

I have a buildr project, that also contains a pom.xml that is used for other projects.
I want to be able to increment the 13.3.1-SNAPSHOT in the pom.xml at the same time as I increment the buildfile VERSION_NUMBER = "13.3.1-SNAPSHOT".

VERSION_NUMBER in My buildfile

```
# Auto-incremented by "release" task.
VERSION_NUMBER = "13.3.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

The command my Jenkins job executes to run this release:

```
buildr clean release NEXT_VERSION=$nextVersion --trace
```

After looking at the buildr site: http://buildr.apache.org/releasing.html
It appears that I might need to do something like

```
Release.next_version = lambda do |next_version| # 13.3.1-SNAPSHOT
    new_version = @NEXT_VERSION@.split(/\./)
    new_version[0] = new_version[0] + 1
    new_version

    ### Run task to update pom.xml <version>
    ### Run task commit pom.xml ???
end
```

Can anyone assist me with this?
How I can edit the pom during the same release?

Comment: when accessing environment arguments via ruby, you normally use the `ENV` constant. in your case this would be `ENV['NEXT_VERSION']`

Answer (score 0):

you could edit the pom file to increase the version during the release task or the Release.next_version call.

```
# code is untested, should just provide an idea
def replace_version(content)
    content.gsub(...)
end
File.open("pom.xml", "r+") { |f| f.write(replace_version(f.read)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Release.next_version` is meant just for determining the next version number if you execute `buildr release`.

Have a look at the `Buildr::Release` class halfway down [`lib/buildr/core/build.rb`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/buildr/trunk/lib/buildr/core/build.rb). You should probably extend the method `update_version_to_next`. Have a look at the various extensions of the release class (just below it) for ideas on how to do the extending.